# I keep getting error "expected identifier"

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    [webView loadRequest: [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: [[[@"http//:www.mobile-boome.weebly.com/boome-webviwer.html" ]]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

the problem is in line 8: xcode says expected identifier but i cannot understand what the problem is so i cannot fix it!
thanks

Comment: Try fixing all of the extra square brackets.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the string literal inside brackets?

Comment: @nhgrif the one that begins and ends with two asterisks, I guess.

Comment: The error is saying that the compiler got to a spot where the only "legal" next token would be an "identifier" (name), and it didn't find one.  Errors of this sort are almost always due to misplaced parens or brackets or whatnot.  In this case the problem was likely after the literal string, since you have it in (multiple) '[]` with no method name following.  Though you would have encountered later errors because earlier '[' characters were not closed.

Comment: In fairness, the Xcode editor likely did this to you.  It likes to insert extra '[' characters at odd times, when it gets confused while "helping" you.

Comment: This usually indicates a typo in or before the line.

Comment: To figure out and avoid it, do less chaining. Chaining makes bugs like this difficult to spot and makes code hard to read. Creating object references inside a method with ARC will make them scoped to the method itself so code is easier to read sand you lose nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You've got extra brackets in that line. Also, both NSURLRequest and NSURL have class methods that simplify constructing instances of the classes.

Try this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http//:www.mobile-boome.weebly.com/boome-webviwer.html"]]];
```